# OpenGL Нужно ли постоянно включать/выключать GL_BLEND

Tags: opengl

когда рисуются прозрачные объекты то включается GL_BLEND, когда рисование заканчивается то GL_BLEND выключается.
Может не нужно выключать, один раз включить при запуске программы и всё? 
Постоянное включение/выключение как то влияет на производительность?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Постоянное включение/выключение как то влияет на производительность?

Да, любая функция, изменяющая контекст, сначала дожидается готовности GPU, а затем стопорит и CPU, и GPU до окончания передачи изменений.

> Может не нужно выключать, один раз включить при запуске программы и всё?

Если вашим контекстом больше никто не пользуется (а в большинстве случаев так оно и есть), то необходимости в восстановлении настроек нет. В придачу, операционная система сама сохраняет их перед обращением к другому OpenGL-приложению и восстанавливает обратно при возвращении к вам.